# Angular $scope.$watch - creating an array and total depending on ng-model/length

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form and want to create a 'completion progress tracker'. If we have ten inputs that are filled in, each input will add 10 to an array, which will render some text: '100% complete'. If you remove or don't have any data in an input, 10 will be remove from the array.

In other words I want to:

1. Watch some items for changes
2. If an item has X length (or some other argument), push 10 to an array
3. If an item has X length removed, remove 10 from the array
4. Create a total of the array

I've been trying things out with `$scope.$watch` and different array methods like `pop()`, `splice()` etc, but i'm not sure how to get this working correctly, and with nice, DRY code.

This is what I have so far (simplified outside of the app with just 3 items).

controller:

```
$scope.userName = 'homer';
$scope.userDescription = 'I really like...';
$scope.userUrl = 'http://something.com'
$scope.theArray = [];

$scope.$watch('userName + userDescription + userUrl', function(){

  $scope.theTotal = 0;

  if($scope.userName.length >= 3) {
    //$scope.theArray.pop(10);
    //$scope.theArray.splice(1,1);
    $scope.theArray.push(10);
  }

  if($scope.userName.length < 3) {
    console.info('oh no!');
    $scope.theArray.pop(10);
  }

  if($scope.userDescription.length > 3) {
    $scope.theArray.push(10);
  }

  if($scope.userUrl.length > 3) {
    $scope.theArray.push(10);
  }

  var x = 0;
  while (x < $scope.theArray.length) {
    $scope.theTotal += $scope.theArray[x];
    x++;
  }

  console.log($scope.theArray)

});
```

template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userName" placeholder="name" />
<input type="text" ng-model="userDescription" placeholder="description" />
<input type="url" ng-model="userUrl" placeholder="url" />

<p>userName length: {{userName.length}}</p>
<p>userDescription length: {{userDescription.length}}</p>
<p>userURL length: {{userUrl.length}}</p>
<br/>
<p><strong>completion: {{theTotal}}</strong></p>
```

But, obviously, this doesn't work correctly. Right now the array just keeps adding and adding, regardless of if the length is below or above the desired amount. I expect this with `$scope.$watch`, I know the changes are triggered when the $watch is in action - is there a way to limit an array `push()` here?

I've tried doing a `pop()` and `push()` at the same time and this 'works', to some degree, but it's not elegant and doesn't help to get it working as desired.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to approach `$scope.$watch` and array methods differently? Or maybe something completely different?

[Here is a codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByXayL?editors=101)

Comment: use hash, instead of array, so it won't add on every keystrokes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't the array for other purposes, you can avoid the array, and only add to the total if a condition is met:

```
$scope.theTotal = 0;
if($scope.userName.length >= 3) {
    $scope.theTotal += 10;
  }

  if($scope.userDescription.length > 3) {
    $scope.theTotal += 10;
  }

  if($scope.userUrl.length > 3) {
    $scope.theTotal += 10;
  }
```

Check this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNXGvY).

Comment: Thank you! That's great. Loads simpler, I think I was overcomplicating the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Tony, let's go through your `$watch` func.
For example I've changed `userName` (and now it's length < 3) we getting into `$watch` function:

1. The first `if` statement ignoring (we get length < 3)
2. We go to a second `if` statement and `pop()` some val from the array
3. And now your algorithm doesn't stop and gets into `if($scope.userDescription.length > 3)`. I didn't change `userDescription` and it's length > 3 - so we add some val to the array.

That's why you still keep adding new items to array.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, however I did understand that it's not working, and why. I wanted to know how it can be achieved with array methods, or another approach.